# How To Set Group Table's Section Header Text

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to set header text for each section of my grouped UITableView.

I tried this code but get error "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView.tag==2)
    {
        if (section == 0)
        {
              return @"test1";
        }
        if (section == 1)
        {
              return @"test2";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Faisal : where did you get EXC_BAD_ACCESS (mean which line)?

Comment: I'm still getting EXC BAD ACCESS error at `int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);`

Comment: are you getting error in simulator or device? I am sure problem is not in above given code. You are not retaining an auto released object and refering it after it got release

Comment: I am getting it both in sim and on device, even when I keep just the method header, and the contents of method JUST an NSLog, it crashes.

Comment: got it working, had to add `return 0;` at the end for fail safe.

Comment: Try use zombies to catch badAccess crashes..See http://www.codza.com/how-to-debug-exc_bad_access-on-iphone

Answer (score 23, accepted):

got it working, had to add `return @"";` at the end for fail safe.

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView.tag==2)
    {
        if (section == 0)
        {
              return @"test1";
        }
        if (section == 1)
        {
              return @"test2";
        }
     }
     return @"";
}
```